# MST algorithms worst scenarios for circular graph/complete graph

Tags: complexity-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Consider a circular graph $G_1$ with $n$ vertices and a complete graph $G_2$ with $m$ vertices. What is the maximum attainable ratio when determining the Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) using Boruvka, Kruskal, or Prim algorithms?

I think about it in the following way:

A complete graph with $v$ vertices has $\dfrac{(v-1)*v}{2}$ edges, and for $m$ edges there are $\dfrac{1 +(\sqrt{1+8m)}}{m}=V$ vertices.

- Kruskal sorts the edges and then adds the cheapest one to MST while checking there are no cycles. Therefore we need to check all edges, and for circular G1 it means we check $n$ edges. For complete graph G2 the complexity is $O(n\log{}n$). This way it is $\dfrac{n}{m*log_{}m}$.
- Prim checks neighbors of the existing MST and adds the cheapest edge. Therefore, for a circular graph $G_1$ it is $n$ again. For a complete graph using adj matrix (in order to get the largest ratio in the answer) the complexity is $O(V^2)$, so the answer is $\dfrac{n}{V^2}$
- Boruvka iterates through each vertex and chooses the cheapest edge interactively. For $G_1$ it is $n$ and for $G_2$ it is in $O(m*log_{}V)$, so $\dfrac{n}{m*log_{}V}$.

Do I miss something and these algorithms behaves differently for a circular graph? Or are there another way to achieve the worst scenario for a complete graph?

Comment: What do you mean by "ratio"?  Ratio between what two quantities?  I encourage you to [edit] your post to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: How for circular graph, Kruskal takes $n$ computations? It will still sort the edges, which will take $O(n \log n)$ time.